# Matlab - Plot normal distribution with unknown mean that is normally distributed with known parameters

Tags: matlab, plot

How can I use Matlab to plot a univariate normal distribution  when it has unknown mean but the mean is also normally distributed with known mean of mean and variance of mean?

Eg. N(mean, 4) and mean ~N(2,8)

Comment: mean, mean, mean, eggs, bacon, mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability), one can write

```
pdf(x) = int(pdf(x | mean) * pdf(mean) dmean)
```

So, we can calculate it in Matlab as follows:

```
% define the constants
sigma_x = 4;
mu_mu = 2;
sigma_mu = 8;

% define the pdf of a normal distribution using the Symbolic Toolbox 
% to be able to calculate the integral
syms x mu sigma 
pdf(x, mu, sigma) = 1./sqrt(2*pi*sigma.^2) * exp(-(x-mu).^2/(2*sigma.^2));

% calculate the desired pdf
pdf_x(x) = int(pdf(x, mu, sigma_x) * pdf(mu, mu_mu, sigma_mu), mu, -Inf, Inf);
pdfCheck = int(pdf_x, x, -Inf, Inf) % should be one

% plot the desired pdf (green) and N(2, 4) as reference (red)
xs = -40:0.1:40;
figure
plot(xs, pdf(xs, mu_mu, sigma_x), 'r')
hold on
plot(xs, pdf_x(xs), 'g')
```

Note that I also checked that the integral of the calculated pdf is indeed equal to one, which is a necessary condition for being a pdf.

[image]

The green plot is the requested pdf. The red plot is added as reference and represents the pdf for a constant mean (equal to the average mean).

Comment: Thank you; I was trying to get a 3D represantation.